# How to increment Datetime field in mongoDB document with atomic operations? And the same in morphia?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, morphia

Well. That's it.

I have a documet with **Datetime** field in it. Now I need to perform atomic operation that will increase this value on some period, f.e. one day.

How to do that?

And ultimately I need to do that via **morphia**, if you know how to, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates are milliseconds since the Unix epoch ([MongoDB Dates](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates)).

So you can query for the document with the date you want to increment and add ([inc/dec in Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating#inc/dec)) the number of ms you need - for example for a day.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. When I am trying to increment Date field I get error: 'Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number'. So I need to convert Date to Timestamp, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ouch, looks like that's waiting to be implemented: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3174 As an alternative, you could explicitly store the date in ms to allow an easy $inc, but that's probably a little too much of a hack...

Comment: Finally I did so - store date as integer.